# count the number of variables equal to a value in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hey I am trying to count the number of times a user has answered the question correctly. This is how my database is stored

userid->questionsid1->correectlyanswer "1"

userid->questionsid2->correectlyanswer "0"

userid->questionsid3->correectlyanswer "0"

userid->questionsid4->correectlyanswer "1"

1 signifying that the answer is correct and 0 being incorrect.

here is the code. The value of questioncode is is correct but the value of in  checkCorrectAnswer string is always null.

```
databaseReference1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            int questionsolved = 0;
            for (DataSnapshot userAnswerSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                String questionCodeKey = userAnswerSnapshot.getKey();
                String checkCorrectAnswer = userAnswerSnapshot.child(questionCodeKey).child("checkAnswerCorrect").getValue(String.class);    
                if (checkCorrectAnswer.equals("1")) {
                    questionsolved = questionsolved + 1;
                }

            }
            questionSolvedTextview.setText(questionsolved + "");
        };

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
});
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the exact JSON (as text, no screenshot) as it is stored in your database. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Yes, please do the edit that @FrankvanPuffelen is requesting. Also could you provide us what your databaseReference1 variable is referring to?

Comment: can you post json data to understand your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got this line wrong.

```
String checkCorrectAnswer = userAnswerSnapshot.child(questionCodeKey).child("checkAnswerCorrect").getValue(String.class);
```

I think you don't need to get the questionCodeKey for this because you are already iterating through the children of your DatabaseReference which I believe is the path to a specific user. If that is the case, you are iterating through the questions already which means you don't have to get the questions because you are already in them. With that, try this and let me know if it works:

```
String checkCorrectAnswer = userAnswerSnapshot.child("checkAnswerCorrect").getValue(String.class);
```

Comment: Glad I could help!